# unicode-math gobbling up glyphs from other package

Tags: unicode-math, font-encodings

I would like Times New Roman as my default font for text and mathematics, and after having tried out several I've found `TeX Gyre` to have the best coverage. But by using `unicode-math` for the mathematics, it seems to cause the `lilyglyphs` package not to display its symbols.
The documentation for the latter requires `fontspec` to be loaded which, if called with the `no-math` option, produces an error.

Compiling the below MWE using `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}

\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}
  6
  \sharp{} %from lilyglyphs
  $\widehat{6}$
\end{document}
```

The MWE includes the Times New Roman numeral but no lilyglyph. The \widehat is also wonky:

[image: mwe output]

Commenting out `unicode-math` and `\setmathfont` shows the lilyglyph correctly and the widehat is correct too, but the numeral is no longer Times New Roman (of course):

[image: commented out]

My desired output is the second picture but with both numerals in Times New Roman. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accent position seems to be just a feature in the font (you see same position without `lilygyphs`) I shifted it a bit here (actually it is shifted too far I think).

The `\sharp` goes as `unicode-math` delays all its definitions until begin document and TeX Gyre Termes Math does not have the character, you can re-instate the `lilyglyphs` version.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\let\zzzsharp\sharp
\AtBeginDocument{\let\sharp\zzzsharp}
\usepackage{unicode-math}



\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}


  6
  \sharp{} %from lilyglyphs
  $\mkern-1mu \widehat{\mkern1mu6}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I fixed a few typos: you're reaching new heights!

Comment: @egreg new laptop, different keyboard so yes typing worse than my usual _excellent_ standard but hopefully temporary... (thanks)

Comment: @egreg do you have a better accent suggestion, I wasn't feeling very creative here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks this works great! Since I'm using quite a number of glyphs from that package and from a few others too is there any way of defining symbols  automatically or am I stuck with redefining each glyph manually?

Comment: As far as I can see, the hat is positioned correctly on letters. Unfortunately, there is no way to substitute accents, yet. Will should try to provide it.

Comment: @pinecone you could encourage https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/548 or https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/477  or https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/465

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, the reports from 2018 don't fill me with hope. Looks like I'll have to ditch `unicode-math` since it conflicts with too many symbols. Your answer answered my question though so I'm going to accept it, thanks!

Comment: In the first lilygyphs there is a missing "l": I didn't edit your answer for fear :-(